# Spring Data fills @LastModifiedDate by not @CreatedDate

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, auditing

I have following Spring Boot sample application.
The crazy thing is if I add `@EnableMongoAuditing` annotation on SampleApplication bean, `lastModifiedDate` would be filled by `createDate` would not. Why is that? I searched the web and many people had problems on emptying `createDate` during an update, but I don't have an update.

Document class:

```
@Document
public class SampleBean implements Persistable<String> {

    @Id
    public String id;
    @CreatedDate
    public LocalDateTime createDate;
    @LastModifiedDate
    public LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

    public String name;

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return id != null;
    }
}
```

Repository Interface:

```
@Repository
public interface SampleBeanRepository extends MongoRepository<SampleBean, String> {
}
```

Rest Controller:

```
@RestController
public class WebService {

    @Autowired
    private SampleBeanRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping("/insert")
    public String insert() {
        SampleBean sampleBean = new SampleBean();
        sampleBean.name = "Prefix" + new Random().nextInt(1000);
        repository.insert(sampleBean);
        return "done";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public Collection<SampleBean> home() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

}
```

Application Config:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class ApplicationConfig {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationConfig.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `isNew()` strategy is the culprit here. Since you have set condition as `id != null`. Everytime your SampleBean is created there will be no id set as per your code snippet, the `isNew()` method will return as false hence only LastModifiedDate will be set by the framework. Either change the `isNew()` method condition to `return id == null;` or just don't implement Persistable interface whatever default strategy for isNew will be picked.